# Extracting values from Html file <td> elements

Tags: html, ubuntu, parsing, awk

I have the following string:

```
<td class="mytest" title="testfile" style="width:20%">0</td>
```

How do I get value within the td elements by using awk? In my case, it is 0.

I am very new to Linux, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to use `awk` for this?

Comment: @Dai This is the only tool that I can think of:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to select your tool I would suggest using [`hxselect`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxselect.html) (from `html-xml-utils`), then if you have `file.txt` holding

```
<td class="mytest" title="testfile" style="width:20%">0</td>
```

it would be as simple as

```
cat file.txt | hxselect -i -c td
```

output

```
0
```

Explanation: `-i` match case insensitive, `-c` print content only, `td` is CSS selector. Disclaimer: there is not newline after `0` as there is not newline inside tag.

However if you are coerced into using installed base, then if linux machine you are using have installed `python` (which if I am not mistaken, recent `Ubuntu` versions do have by default), you might harness [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) as follows, create `tdextract.py` file with following content

```
import sys
from html.parser import HTMLParser
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.insidetd = False
        super().__init__()

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "td":
            self.insidetd = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "td":
            self.insidetd = False

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.insidetd:
            sys.stdout.write(data)

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(sys.stdin.read())
```

then do

```
cat file.txt | python tdextract.py
```

which will give same output as `hxselect` described earlier. Be warned that `python` use indentation for marking blocks, so it is crucially important to keep number of leading spaces.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be to use [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) (`xmllint --html`) with an [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) to extract the value.

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
data='<td class="mytest" title="testfile" style="width:20%">0</td>'
value=$(xmllint --html --xpath '//html/body/td/text()' - <<< "$data")
echo "$value"
```

Output:

```
0
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I tried that in my personal VM and it works! uncourtly, my company server doesn't have xmllint in Ubuntu. I am not sudo user and It is kind of inconvenient to get approval to install the new package on the company server due to security compliance.

Comment: Your company needs to provide the right tools for you to do your job. It's not about inconvenience, it's about doing your job properly.

Comment: I tned to agree with @glennjackman - Adding a tool like `xmllint` to the toolbox should be a no-brainer for those in charge if you tell them that you'd like to use a commonly known, well tested, suited and stable tool for the task, rather than to roll your own.

Comment: Another way to say it to the powers-that-be: it's less expensive to provide you with a common tool than for you to spend your time re-inventing it.

Comment: `xmllint` is pretty cheap... The time to master `xpath` I don't know though. I have only scratched the surface of what can be done with that.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for advice. I will try to open the ticket:) Sorry for the typo in my first comment( Uncourtly=>Unfortunately). I should disable autocorrect in my phone...

Answer (score 1):

If your input is always that regular and you don't have and can't install XML-aware tools then using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed 's:<td.*>\(.*\)</td>:\1:' file
0
```

I'm using sed instead of awk because simple substitutions on individual lines like this is what sed is best suited for. With GNU awk you could do this with the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,"<td.*>(.*)</td>",a){print a[1]}' file
0
```

but with a POSIX awk it'd be a bit more cryptic (there are alternative approaches of course):

```
$ awk 'sub("</td>","") && sub("<td.*>","")' file
0
```

Think about what the above is doing and test it to make sure you don't get any false matches. It's always much easier to match what you want than it is to not match similar strings you don't want.